# Add new fields in tt_content for all contentelements in typo3

Tags: typo3-8.x

I tried to add new fields in tt_content for all Contentelemets - typo3 8.7.12. I used this tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/#example-2-extending-the-tt-content-table
 - but nothing happens. I can't find any entry in the contentelements. the field iss added to the database.

I tried this part of the tutorial with noch Problems: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/#example-1-extending-the-fe-users-table

And I build a custom contentelement without any problems.

Could anyone give me a hint to find the problem?

Thanks
Volker

Answer (score 1):

So a new field is shown in every variant of a record you need to add the field to the field list of all the existing variants.

This can be done with:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tt_content',
    'tx_examples_options, tx_examples_special'
);
```

Be careful where you add your field:
Modifying palettes might add the field only to those variants where this palette is used, but not all palettes are used in every variant.
Also adding a field after another field might not work as expected if the field is not shown in some variants.

On success you can see your new field in the BE in the `Configuration` module:
select `$GLOBALS['TCA'] (Table configuration array)` in the dropdown and open the tree at
`tt_content -> types -> ? -> showitem` or
`tt_content -> palettes -> ? -> showitem` there your field should be listed.

the configuration of your field should be visible at
`tt_content -> columns -> <your_field> -> ...`

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Verifying/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I'm sorry, but nothing happens - where should appear anything?

cu
Volker

Comment: I enhanced my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot again, I will test it and give you response.